# Отображение двух ListView

Tags: android, listview

Доброго  времени  суток, господа.
Есть разметка с двумя `ListView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">
    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/lvLauncherTool"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </ListView>
    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/lvLauncherData"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400pt">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

По  каким  причинам  не устанавливается  второй?  То  есть, первый я вижу на  экране, а второго нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первый просто вытесняет второй из-за match_parent. Попробуйте установить android:layout_weight="1" для обоих или (что наверное даже лучше) использовать RelativeLayout.

Comment: Почти  помогло.
По  задумке  я  их хочу  вертикально  друг  за  другом  расположить.
vertical  я  уже  поставил, но  теперь  у  меня  на  пол  экрана  первый и  на  пол  экрана  второй. Я  так  понимаю  мне  нужно  linearlayout  поменять  на  что то  чтобы  два  списка  шли  друг  за  другом  и  прокручивались  вместе. При  этом  первый  список  определенного  размера  по  высоте

Comment: @alexmx, я не уверен, что у вас это получится сделать в таком виде. Все-таки ListView рассчитан на другое. Возможно, здесь стоит просто создать использовать один ListView и сделать к нему кастомный адаптер.

Answer (score 1):

Если первый определенного размера по высоте, можно вставить его в header ко второму, тогда они будут оба прокручиваться нормально!

Answer (score 0):

Вот так попробуйте

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView2"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: По  ширине  они  у  меня  не  пройдут  в  том  то  и  беда(содержимое  широкое), а  так  они  у  меня  оба  на  два  разных  кастомных  адаптера  подключены.

Comment: а  как  насчет  ScrollView, это  осуществимо  или  не  стоит  пытаться?